# Xcode merge dictionary to a dictionary inside an array

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, merge

Any methods to add-on for the dictionary inside an array? I was trying to use

```
[[parentArray objectAtIndex:1] addEntriesFromDictionary:newDictionary];
```

but I get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException, 'reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI addEntriesFromDictionary:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDictionary` is immutable, and as such, has no such selector.

You want an `NSMutableDictionary`, which has the `addEntriesFromDictionary:` selector.

Or an `NSMutableArray` would allow you to grab the immutable dictionary, make a new immutable dictionary from that plus your new dictionary, and then store the combined immutable dictionary back at the index the original dictionary was originally at.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just did what exactly you mentioned. By create new NSMutableDictionary and replace with original Parent Array.